# Upgrade of Linux Subsystem for Windows 10 (WSL) to Ubuntu 16.04 not working

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to upgrade to the latest WSL and used the [official upgrade procedure](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/10/19/wsl-adds-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-support/), i.e.

```
lxrun /uninstall /full
```

and then

```
lxrun /install
```

However, `lsb_release -a` tells me I still run the 14.04 release and not 16.04? I tried Powershell, Command Prompt with and without Admin privileges and rebooted a couple of times. Windows is all up-to-date.

Any hints?

Comment: Are you on Windows build 14951 or later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 in WSL became available in Insider build 14951. It is also in version 1703, the "Creators Update" which is in [limited release](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/04/25/windows-10-creators-update-rollout-first-phase-update/#2z8BaYgwe3H4LzjB.97). (As of 27 July 2017, [full release](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/07/27/windows-10-creators-update-fully-available-for-all-windows-10-customers/#84lcLpImYjyr5VAq.97).)

However, you may be able upgrade to Ubuntu 16 even if you don't have a late build of Windows. According to [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/upgrade-bash-windows-10-ubuntu-16-04-lts), you can do a release upgrade. I haven't tried it. It is unsupported. For all I know, it may make your WSL go up in smoke, so do a backup first.

Comment: "Actually you cannot upgrade to 16.04 unless you upgrade to 1703." True, if you want to do it in the supported way. But there is a workaround for earlier versions.

Comment: "The current general release, of Windows 10 is 1703, which has WSL 1604 not 1404." Good to know. I'm stuck on 1607 no matter how many times I run Windows Update, but at least some folks are there already.